# How do I perform Cloudinary transformations with conditional logic?

Tags: carrierwave, cloudinary

I am converting a carrierwave uploader to use Cloudinary. I have a couple of methods like these, that output hashes in the Cloudinary format, but unfortunately inside of a version block you don't have access to outside methods. I am wondering what the best way to do this is with respect to cloudinary, or if it is even possible.

```rb
def custom_crop
  if model.cropping?
    cloudinary_transformation({x: model.crop_x.to_i,
     y: model.crop_y.to_i,
     width: model.crop_w.to_i,
     height: model.crop_h.to_i,
     crop: :crop})
  end
end

def watermark
  if model.respond_to?(:watermarking?) && model.watermarking?
    cloudinary_transformation({overlay: "watermark_x8b0vp",
     gravity: :south_east,
     x: 0,
     y: 106})
  end
end
```

The code I ideally want to run is something like this:

```rb
version :cropped_original do
  process :custom_crop
  process :watermark
  resize_to_fill(81, 50, :center)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the transformations you need from the process methods. However, in this case, you probably want to chain them. You the do this as follows:

```
def custom_crop_and_watermark
  transformation = []
  if model.cropping?
    transformation << {x: model.crop_x.to_i,
     y: model.crop_y.to_i,
     width: model.crop_w.to_i,
     height: model.crop_h.to_i,
     crop: :crop}
  end
  if model.respond_to?(:watermarking?) && model.watermarking?
    transformation << {overlay: "watermark_x8b0vp", gravity: :south_east, x: 0, y: 106}
  end
  {:transformation=>transformation}
end
```

Comment: Related to this, see how model.cropping? is conditional. Our process is that someone uploads a photo, then they are presented with a cropper that updates the crop params for the image. It isn't clear how to update the photo (recreate! was the way in carrierwave), with the new crop params. Is this possible with Cloudinary?

Comment: When you will update the model with the coordinates, further calls to cropped_original.url will be updated image url and return the cropped image.